# Drawing on a Canvas and resize the canvas after drawing

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint

I am drawing WaveForm of the sounds inside of Canvas based on Soundbitrate but canvas covering full-screen width of the device but I want to draw canvas width as per the inside content of canvas.
Does anyone have any idea how to scale the size of canvas after the draw?
Here is the draw() method inside my canvas.

````
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();

        if (mSoundFile == null)
            return;

        if (mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel == null)
            computeIntsForThisZoomLevel();

        // Draw waveform
        int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        int start = mOffset;
        int width = mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel.length - start;
        int ctr = measuredHeight / 2;

        if (width > measuredWidth)
            width = measuredWidth;

        // Draw grid
        double onePixelInSecs = pixelsToSeconds(1);
        boolean onlyEveryFiveSecs = (onePixelInSecs > 1.0 / 50.0);
        double fractionalSecs = mOffset * onePixelInSecs;
        int integerSecs = (int) fractionalSecs;
        int i = 0;
        while (i <width) {
            i++;
            fractionalSecs += onePixelInSecs;
            int integerSecsNew = (int) fractionalSecs;
            if (integerSecsNew != integerSecs) {
                integerSecs = integerSecsNew;
                if (!onlyEveryFiveSecs || 0 == (integerSecs % 5)) {
                    canvas.drawLine(i, 0, i, measuredHeight, mGridPaint);
                }
            }
        }

        i=0;
        while (i < width-1) {
            i++;
            Paint paint;
            if (i + start >= mSelectionStart &&
                    i + start < mSelectionEnd) {
                paint = mSelectedLinePaint;
            } else {
                drawWaveformLine(canvas, i, 0, measuredHeight,
                        mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint);
                paint = mUnselectedLinePaint;
            }
            drawWaveformLine(
                    canvas, i,
                    ctr - mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                    ctr + 1 + mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                    paint);

            if (i + start == mPlaybackPos) {
                canvas.drawLine(i /*+ (canvas.getWidth() / 2)*/, 0, i/* + (canvas.getWidth() / 2)*/, measuredHeight, mPlaybackLinePaint);
            }
        }

}```
````

Comment: If the view is covering device width then its canvas will also do so.

Comment: Yes, I want to set my view size the same as my canvas drawing only, As like wrap_content. but how to set that? Any idea about it?

Comment: as I set view's width "wrap_content" but still its cover whole screen width.

Comment: Do you know what will be your canvas size? If you know, you can set the view's size as that size. Then your canvas size will automatically be equal to that size;

Comment: canvas.scale()...........